# Soft keyboard enter key event handle

Tags: android

I want to do some stuff on soft keyboard enter key press. See my code and output below. It executes twice, but I want it to be executed only once. How to fix it?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                Log.e("test","--------- on enter");
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

[image: This is my output for this]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The best way possible:**

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    Log.d(TAG, "enter_key_called");
}
```

Comment: Should probably go for ACTION_UP instead, so the user can cancel the event my removing his or hers finger? And add KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER for those ones.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html: `Called when a hardware key is dispatched to a view.`.
This won't work for the soft keyboard.

Comment: setting inputType="text" on the EditText view, makes it work for me for the soft keyboard